# My Java logger makes a new log file every time the program repeats

Tags: java, logging

```
if (outcome == 1) {
    Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("MyLog");
    FileHandler fh = new FileHandler("C:\\Temp\\Dice_Roll_J\\Logs.txt", true);
    logger.addHandler(fh);
    logger.setLevel(Level.ALL);
    SimpleFormatter formatter = new SimpleFormatter();
    fh.setFormatter(formatter);
    logger.log(Level.INFO, "Outcome 1.");                        
} 

if (outcome == 2) {
    Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("MyLog");
    FileHandler fh = new FileHandler("C:\\Temp\\Dice_Roll_J\\Logs.txt", true);
    logger.addHandler(fh);
    logger.setLevel(Level.ALL);
    SimpleFormatter formatter = new SimpleFormatter();
    fh.setFormatter(formatter);
    logger.log(Level.INFO, "Outcome 2");
}
```

This program is in a while loop, every time it goes onto an if statement and logs the info into the file, it does that. But the problem is that it also makes another file called Logs.txt.1 and if i roll it again, Logs.txt.2 and so on. It also makes files called Logs.txt.lck.

**How do I fix this? Any help will be greatly appreciated**

Comment: What Logger class are you using?

Comment: What is `outcome` ?

Comment: @azro `outcome` is a randomized variable from 1, 6

Comment: @nicomp do you mean the `FileHandler`

Comment: All that repeated code to just have a single string different? Ouch!

Comment: @John3136 the program is bigger then just 6 if statements.

Comment: `logger.log(Level.INFO, "Outcome {}", outcome)` can save you about 45 lines of code.

Comment: A good advice: Post your program on codereview.stackexchange.com and let it be reviewed by someone. That will solve the logger problem that comes from the bigger problem, your code with all it's duplications and duplicate declarations.

Comment: @MasterHackerLOIS even if it's bigger than 6 if statements(?), duplicate code is very bad and you'll have troubles if you code like this!

Comment: I fixed it, i had to move that file handler ouside of the loop and put `fh.close();` after the logger puts the log into the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("MyLog");
    FileHandler fh = new FileHandler("C:\\Temp\\Dice_Roll_J\\Logs.txt", true);
    logger.addHandler(fh);
    logger.setLevel(Level.ALL);
    SimpleFormatter formatter = new SimpleFormatter();
    fh.setFormatter(formatter);
```

Move that out of each if statement outside of the loop so the only thing left is the `logger.log(Level.INFO, "Outcome x");` in the if statements and after that put `fh.close();`

Answer (score 1):

You seem to use this [constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/logging/FileHandler.html#FileHandler-java.lang.String-boolean-) right, my only guess is that the previous handler is still in possession of the file so the new handler just creates a new file. Try to create only one handler outside of your loop and using it for your logging purpose.